# Partial fractions - different results when done in steps than not

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

We have: $\frac 1 {(1-x)(1+x)(1-2x)}$

If I do the partial fractions straight: $\frac 1 {(1-x)(1+x)(1-2x)}= \frac a {1-x} + \frac b {1+x} + \frac c {1-2x}$

I get: $a=-\frac 12, b = \frac 1 6, c=\frac 4 3$.

But when I do it in steps, i.e: $\frac 1 {(1-x^2)(1-2x)}=\frac a {1-x^2} +  \frac b {1-2x} $

I get: $a=2, b=-1$, then again partial fractions: $\frac 2 {1-x^2}=\frac a {1-x} + \frac b {1+x}$ Get: $a=1, b=-1$

In the first method I got: $\frac {-\frac 12} {1-x} + \frac {\frac 1 6} {1+x} + \frac {\frac 4 3} {1-2x}$

But in steps: $\frac {1} {1-x} - \frac {1} {1+x} - \frac {1} {1-2x}$

How is that possible? Shouldn't they be the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\frac 1 {(1-x^2)(1-2x)}\ne\frac a {1-x^2} +  \frac b {1-2x}$

$\frac 1 {(1-x^2)(1-2x)}=\frac {a+bx} {1-x^2} +  \frac c {1-2x}$

One finds that $a=-1/3$, $b=-2/3$ and $c=4/3$.

Comment: Ohh right! well, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.

Comment: conceptual takeaway: the form of the numerator is the potential form of a remainder from polynomial long division. which means that the degree of the (generic) numerator must be one less than the degree of the denominator--if the degrees match, we can polynomial divide further; if the degree is more than one less, we are not being generic enough.